# JavaScript object returning static method and himself as method

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do:

```
foo()      // return string "foo"
foo.bar()  // return string "bar"
```

?

I tried to experiment with functions and objects. But nothing happened.

Comment: You want something like this:-
function foo(){ return "foo"; }
foo.bar = function(){ return "bar"; }

Comment: do you want foo() to return "foo", that would be `function foo () {return "foo"}` or do you want to return the name of a called function which would be `console.log(foo.name);` which would be pretty pointless because you enter the name already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function foo() {
   return "foo";
}
foo.bar = function() {
   return "bar";
};
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
var foo = function() {
    return "foo";
};
foo.bar = function() {
    return "bar";
}
```

JS functions are a type of object so you can assign properties/methods to them the same as for any other object.

Answer (score 0):

You can call either a function or a class named `foo` but you can't have both as far as I know. Correct me if I'm wrong. Why would you want a class and a function with the same way anyway? *I'm assuming that that's what you want as there is little info in your post*

To define a function use this

```
function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

And call it like in your example.

To define a class do it like this ([here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) are some other ways to do it).

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}
```

And again, call it like you did in your example.

Comment: _"Correct me if I'm wrong."_ - OK, um...you're wrong. Try out the code from my answer. By the way, Javascript doesn't have classes per se, but if you call a JS function with `new` it behaves a bit like a class would in some other languages. The word "class" usually implies something that you can create instances of, but your `var foo = {...}` is just a singleton object with a method...